# Simple web app with authorization for testing in JMeter

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I'm looking for simple web application for testing in JMeter. The app needs to have authorization and more then 500 code lines (or more). I searched on github and opensource projects, but on github it's hard to find with authorization, opensource projects on the other side are too big for my purpose.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Homework assignment?

Answer (score -1):

This URL provides some interesting examples of authorization but the 500 lines requirement is not here (I doubt you'll find anything):

- http://httpbin.org/